# How to iterate over rows with vectorization

Tags: pandas

Here is my code for creating a new column called 'Re' in my Dataframe `list12` using the function that I defined as `findindex` where the variable `B` is the corresponding index of each row that satisfies the condition `(list12['FPI']==6) & (list12['Firm Name']==x[I])`. head rows of file and file3 are shown below.

```
CUSIP   Firm Name   Date Record FPI forecasting period(days)    Median
0   00846U10    A   1999-12-16  0   1825    20.50
1   00846U10    A   1999-12-16  6   46  0.23
2   00846U10    A   1999-12-16  7   136 0.30
3   00846U10    A   1999-12-16  8   228 0.29
4   00846U10    A   1999-12-16  1   320 1.11

Global Company Key  Data Date   Fiscal Year Fiscal Quarter  Ticker Symbol   CUSIP   Common Shares Outstanding   Earnings Per Share (Basic) - Including Extraordinary Items  Earnings Per Share (Basic) - Excluding Extraordinary Items  Earnings Per Share (Basic) - Including Extraordinary Items.1
156794  126554  1998/01/31  1998    1   A   00846U101   NaN 0.42    0.42    0.42
156795  126554  1998/04/30  1998    2   A   00846U101   NaN 0.24    0.24    0.67
156796  126554  1998/07/31  1998    3   A   00846U101   NaN 0.14    0.14    0.81
156797  126554  1998/10/31  1998    4   A   00846U101   NaN -0.13   -0.13   0.68
156798  126554  1999/01/31  1999    1   A   00846U101   NaN 0.19    0.19    0.19

x = ['A','AA','AABA','AAL','AAP','AAPL','ABBV','ABC','ABMD','ABT']
list12 = file.loc[file['Firm Name'].isin(x)]
#file3
def findindex(list12,A,B):
    diff = pd.to_datetime(file3[file3['Ticker Symbol']==A]['Data Date']) - pd.to_datetime(list12.loc[B,'Date Record'])
    if len(diff[(diff < pd.to_timedelta(0))])>0:
        indexmax = (diff[(diff < pd.to_timedelta(0))].idxmax())
        #list11.loc[index,'N'] = file3.loc[indexmax,'Data Date']
        list12.loc[B,'Re']= list12.loc[B,'Median']+file3.loc[indexmax-1,'Earnings Per Share (Basic) - Including Extraordinary Items']+file3.loc[indexmax-2,'Earnings Per Share (Basic) - Including Extraordinary Items']+file3.loc[indexmax-3,'Earnings Per Share (Basic) - Including Extraordinary Items']
    return list12.loc[B,'Re']
    
    
    
    
list12['Re']=""
for i in range(len(x)):
    list12.loc[(list12['FPI']==6) & (list12['Firm Name']==x[i]), 'Re']=findindex(list12,x[i],(list12['FPI']==6) & (list12['Firm Name']==x[i]))
list12
```

I was trying to vectorize the codes and avoid using for loop. The problem I am having is that it returns an empty 'Re' column when I run the code. I assume that I did not iterate the rows correctly, but I do not know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to define a minimum executable example when submitting a question. In your example `file` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.